# Flexbox flex-start does not working within flex container

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I am new to Flexbox and have read a lot about it online mainly using [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Currently I am trying to do something very simple on a react native app but failing miserably. I have tried for many hours before posting this question, and have run out of ideas. Was hoping someone would be able to help.

**Desired effect**

Referring to the image below I would like the red box (my logo) to be aligned to the top of the page and centered horizontally and would like the green box to be aligned vertically and horizontally in the center. I don't want my logo to pushing the green box down. The logo just needs to fill the height up until the green box. My logo is an SVG and will auto scale its size based on height.

[image]

**Here is my attempt**

```
 <View
        style={[
            {
                display: 'flex',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                backgroundColor: Colour.white,
                justifyContent: 'center',
            },
        ]}>
        <Logo style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'flex-start', alignContent: 'center' }} />
        <Card
            containerStyle={{
                width: '85%',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                backgroundColor: Colour.white,
            }}>
            <Input placeholder="USERNAME" containerStyle={LoginStyles.usernameInput} />
            <Input preset="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
            <Text preset="link" style={LoginStyles.resetPasswordText}>
                RESET PASSWORD
            </Text>
        </Card>
    </View>
```

But with my implementation it doesn't work at all it looks like I can horizontally align the components but the logo doesn't appear at the top of the view and it doesn't fill until the card layout instead its pushing the card view down and centers with it. I read somewhere also flex direction on react native by default is column

Really hoping somebody could help! Lost a lot of time trying to implement this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this as this is untested code but if you set your card to `flex:2` and your logo to `flex:1` what's going to happen if your screen will be split in 3 where your card is taking 2 of the 3 "spaces" available! So it's going to be in the center and your logo will just ocupy that 1 "space" up top

```
 <View
    style={[
        {
            display: 'flex',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: Colour.white,
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
    ]}>
    <Logo style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'flex-start', alignContent: 'center' }} />
    <Card
        containerStyle={{
            flex: 2,
            width: '85%',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            backgroundColor: Colour.white,
        }}>
        <Input placeholder="USERNAME" containerStyle={LoginStyles.usernameInput} />
        <Input preset="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
        <Text preset="link" style={LoginStyles.resetPasswordText}>
            RESET PASSWORD
        </Text>
    </Card>
</View>
```

Yet again... I haven't tested the code but in theory it should work